# VueJS InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a screen that displays an input field for each element of a list.

```
<div v-for="(destiny, index) in destinations" :key="index">
  <md-field>
    <md-input
      :id="destiny.id"
      v-model="destiny.name"
      type="text"
      required
      @focus="destinyOnFocus(index)"
    ></md-input>
  </md-field>
</div>
```

This screen has a button that when clicked adds an element to the list. When the list is incremented VueJS renders a new input type field.
When the user clicks on the input field, the destinyOnFocus function is called.

```
destinyOnFocus(index) {
  this.destinationsAutocomplete[index] = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(this.destinations[index].id));
  this.destinationsAutocomplete[index].addListener("place_changed", () => {
    this.calculateRoutes();
  });
}
```

When destinyOnFocus is called, a google maps Autocomplete object is created and a listener is associated with it.
When the user selects a place, the calculateRoutes routine is called.
Everything up to this point is working smoothly.
The problem happens when I try to load this screen with a list that has been previously saved.
I load the routes into destinations and manually call the destinyOnFocus(index) function to create the Autocomplete object and associate the listener.
But here the problem occurs, the element has not yet been rendered on the screen and I cannot create the Autocomplete object.
The following error is returned: InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle/Codepen/etc for this issue with these dependencies loaded?

Comment: I can't, because my GoogleMaps API_KEY is not public. The problem happens because i try to create a google maps autocomplete object informing an input that has not been rendered on screen yet. But although the console displays this error to me, the screen works perfectly. Once the component is rendered on screen, Autocomplete works perfectly.

Comment: For each element loaded from the backend, I add an element to the destination list. Each destination list element will generate a new input field on the screen. Next I create an Autocomplete object and associate it with this input field, turning it into an Autocomplete field. Since I want the component to render and already be of type Autocomplete, I manually call the destinyOnFocus function. In normal screen operation, the user clicks the add input button and only when he gets the input focus that the destinyOnFocus function is called to turn the button into an autocomplete.

Comment: But my problem is that on screen load, the fields have not yet been rendered for me to call destinyOnFocus.

Comment: Without some kind of working example it’s gong to be difficult to provide a specific solution. What you will probably need to do is move this element into a child component. Within that component you can use $el and a lifecycle hook like mounted to reference the DOM element only after it’s been made available. Once again without a working example, it’s not practical to find an exact solution. Btw you can always create another api key that could use then delete after the issue is resolved.